# "Run Administrative Console" menu becomes disabled with RAD 9 and WebSphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, rad, websphere-8

I'm using RAD 9.0 with a local WebSphere Application Server v8.5. Twice the "Run Administrative Console" menu has become disabled:

[image: Run Administrative Console is disabled]

This happened randomly; it was working one day when I left, and the next morning it isn't working.

When this happened before, the only way I found to fix it was to create a new profile, which required me to set up all of my data sources and environment variables all over again. I don't want to do that again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Very strange. Check if you can access console directly via browser, not from Eclipse, using `http://localhost:port/ibm/console`. Since looks like you have 3 WAS profiles, the port will be probably 9062 (but you can check it in the logs or try 60 and 61).

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. This is a useful work-around to this problem. You can get into the admin console with a web browser by going to a URL in that form. The next comment is a way to find your port number.

Comment: 1. In the Servers view, right-click on the server and select "Properties"
2. In the left pane, click "WebSphere Application Server".
3. Click "Open SystemOut.log in editor.
4. In the SystemOut.log, search for the word "adminconsole". You should find a line that ends in something like this: Web Module adminconsole redirector has been bound to admin_host[*:9068,*:9051]. The port numbers might be different. Note the first port number listed in this line. This is the port number you should try for getting to your Admin Console using the URL "http://localhost:port/ibm/console"

Comment: I found another work-around. If this problem is happening in one workspace, and I make a whole new workspace, the problem doesn't happen in the new workspace. (However, if I go back to the old workspace, the problem still happens there.)

Comment: I'm going to leave this at "no answers" for a day or two just in case someone knows how to actually fix this. However, with two work-arounds, this issue is no longer a real problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I have ran into this issue before, but it did not occur randomly. Have you tried running RAD as administrator? In windows 7 you can do this by going to the start menu then right-clicking on the RAD application and choosing run as administrator. I have found that the administrative console is not available if I do not start RAD this way.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Delete your server in the "Servers" tab. 
2 - Add a new server. 
3 - Restart your operating system.

It worked for me.

Comment: It worked because I was logged in as another user in windows.
If the user is different from the user who created the workspace the admin console is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a way to completely fix this, but I have two easy work-arounds in the comments which should be elevated to "answers".

(1) Access the console with a browser at the address "localhost:port/ibm/console". The port number can be found as follows:

a. After starting your server, in the Servers view, right-click on the server and select "Properties"

b. In the left pane, click "WebSphere Application Server".

c. Click "Open SystemOut.log in editor.

d. In the SystemOut.log, search for the word "adminconsole". You should find a line that ends in something like this: Web Module adminconsole redirector has been bound to admin_host[:9068,:9051]. The port numbers might be different. Note the first port number listed in this line. This is the port number you should try for getting to your Admin Console using the URL.

(2) Create a new workspace. In my experience, the problem will not be occurring in the new workspace.